# Is there any real difference between "and" and "wheres" in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this query

```
 from a in objects
 where a.property1 == 2
 && a.property2 == 3
 select a
```

and

```
from a in objects
where a.property1 == 2
where a.property2 == 3
select a
```

I was wondering if there is any real difference in how the statements get executed and what would be the benefits with using either

As of right now my question regards linq to objects

Comment: Linq to objects, entities, xml, sql?

Comment: I didn't know you could use `where` twice like the way you are using it.

Comment: @Burb, the result would simply be the chain of Where extension calls `.Where(...).Where(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first case will be converted to:

```
objects.Where(a => a.property1 == 2 && a.property2 == 3);
```

while the latter one will be converted to:

```
objects.Where(a => a.property1 == 2).Where(a => a.property2 == 3);
```

The difference is that the latter will be filtered twice, while the first one is doing the comparisons in a lambda.

This is assuming LINQ-to-Objects; other providers will depend on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the two statements are identical since C# only evaluates the right-hand-side of an AND operation if the left-hand-side is true.

If C# wasn't lazy with AND evaluation, the sequential WHERE evaluations might provide fairly significant performance boosts in cases where most items fail to satisfy the first criterion (or the second criterion is an expensive evaluation). As it stands, however, C# is lazy by default and thus performs comparably to the lazily evaluated LINQ.

Comment: If C# weren't lazily evaluating the `&&`, then LINQ would simply check both properties before accepting the item into the result.  It's very hard to say that doing that would perform better than looping over the first result, and then filtering again (causing more memory allocation), because things vary. I would guess that the former would be faster in most cases--doing it all in one pass--particularly because it will immediately reduce the size of the list, which means less memory allocated for it internally.  Since it's lazy, then it will definitely be faster in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a difference depends on the underlying LINQ provider. The LINQ provider is responsible to translate your LINQ query to an underlying functional representation for example SQL.

The real difference for me is readability. Two chained where statements decrease readability.